# how to efficiently build angular and spring boot app

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am trying to build a spring boot/angular app.
I want to run it locally while building the front end login/logout flow. So I have angular running on 4200 and spring boot running on 8080.
The problem is that when I login from angluar the re-direct url etc points back to 8080. 
Is there a simple way that I can run spring boot and angular on the same port and have the front refresh everytime I make a change to a file like what is happening now with "ng serve"

Comment: I guess, it is easier to change the redirect address.

Answer (score 0):

No.

You cannot use the same port for two different processes in any circumstances. You should best change the redirect address as Henry recommended.